# Can't connect to Samba server from specific machine

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, samba

I'm hosting a Samba share on a remote Ubuntu 16.04 VM that I can access from one computer running Windows 10 but not another, and I am having trouble diagnosing the issue. The computers are in separate locations with different external IPs. I am authenticating with a `\` before my username to avoid specifying a domain.

The working computer is joined to a domain, and the non-working computer isn't. Shouldn't be an issue but I thought I'd mention it.

For the non-working computer, I am prompted for credentials when mapping a network drive, but after I enter the credentials I get the error "Windows cannot access [share]. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network."

I can ping the server just fine from the non-working computer, and I do not have any IP restrictions on my firewall rules. Any tips?

Comment: You need to make sure you share the SAMBA share with the domain and the users that exist on the computer not connected to the domain

Comment: Is samba domain joined?

Comment: No, the Samba server is not on a domain. Config just has the default `workgroup = WORKGROUP`.

Comment: @Ramhound, I haven't specifically shared Samba with the domain of the working computer, and in any case it shouldn't matter with the preceding \.

Comment: If you obviously have shared the files with the domain because it works on a pc connected to the domain...

Comment: Not true, because I'm not using my domain credentials to connect to the server.

Comment: List the users who can access a random file on the SAMBA share.  This VM which machine is it hosted on?

Comment: Security tab lists "Everyone", "Unix Group\user", and "UBUNTU\user" where "user" is my account name. I tried connecting with "UBUNTU\user" on the non-working machine but with no luck. VM is hosted by Linode.

Comment: [smbclient -L is net rpc share list -U $USERNAME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102924/list-samba-shares-and-current-users) the user would be if I recall my samba syntax would need to specify the machine name then the username

Comment: I've tried [IP]\user and [MachineName]\user with no luck.